# Why were these flags on an answer that gave the original source (non-comic) of a quote on a question that wanted the comic source declined?

Tags: discussion, flagging, specific-answer

I (and a few other people) flagged [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/113811) as *Not An Answer*. This is the full text of the answer:

> This quote is a paraphrase of Luke 12:48 where Jesus says "to whom much is given, much will be required"

The question - [What is the context of the quote “With great power comes great responsibility”?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/3857/33591)- however is looking for **the first instance of the quote in the universe**. Specifically:

> However, was the quote also present in the comics?

This does **not answer the question asked**. Why were these flags declined and the post not deleted?

[image: declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer]

Comment: UPDATE: It's now been deleted by the community via review.

Comment: @Valorum you seem to be misunderstanding the intended use of the "not an answer" flag. As we've never had a meta on this site specifically about it (to my knowledge, I've not worked through the whole backlog yet) it goes by the main site policy (which I don't have a link for but paraphrased no is the case) that wrong answers are STILL answers. Whether we agree with this or not is our of our hands, NAA is purely for *comments* or *gibberish* and the like, not answers that are simply *wrong* as stated in the flag comment

Comment: @Edlothiad - I've always taken it to mean "*Is an answer, but not one that actually answers the question asked"* - For example if you asked the names of the Fantastic Four and I responded with a rant about how dumb Dr Doom is.

Comment: This would be another case, that is not a wrong answer, but not an answer at all. This is merely a *wrong* answer.

Comment: @Edlothiad - Unless OP can give a solid explanation why he feels that a bible quote is actually the progenitor of Peter's line about "great responsibility", it's not an answer, just a thing that's kinda similar.

Comment: @Valorum - nope. It's an answer. It's a bad answer. But an answer.

Comment: @DVK - it does not answer the question asked though. **An *attempt* to answer the question does not automatically make something an answer.** In this case they provided the original source of the quote, but the question wanted the comic source. It did not answer what the question wanted.

Comment: @Mithrandir - yes, that's what differenciates a poor answer from a non-answer.

Comment: @Mithrandir Attempt to answer =/= answer, yes - and **"not an answer" flags are for things that don't even *attempt* to answer**. It says so [right there in the flag description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVtq9.png).

Comment: @Rand - I think you'll find that there's [room for disagreement on that](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1383/can-answers-be-off-topic-how-to-deal-with-answers-that-address-legal-issues/1385#comment1551_1385).

Comment: @Mithrandir The comment you link to seems to be drawing a distinction between "*answers that do not actually answer or even address the question*" and "*posts that aren't attempts at answering*", but to me those seem to be the same thing, and both fall under (my understanding of) what the NaA flag is meant to be used for.

Answer (score 5):

**The post did attempt to answer the question.**

The NAA flag is always a fickle mistress... I would always recommend the LQP flag if it is available. If not, flag as NAA at your own risk, as many things (including this answer) do attempt to provide an answer.

An attempt at an answer is generally all that is required by SE standards. Even though this post did not follow the instructions of the question it was indeed an *attempt*; therefore the NAA flag was not appropriate.

---

**The extra step of flagging as NAA was probably not necessary.**

That being said, you probably should have just voted to delete the post without flagging it. As [discussed here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3293/is-deleting-really-wrong-answers-ok-according-to-the-rules) a "wrong" answer can and should be deleted if it is of low enough quality. The post did have a negative score, which is why it was eligible for deletion in the first place and having a look at the edit/review history it seems you did vote to delete.

Comment: "*As discussed here a "wrong" answer can and should be deleted if it is of low enough quality.*" - um, no, that's not what it says there. The exact quote (from a then mod) is "**I'd recommend a downvote and a comment indicating why it's wrong.**" - *not* deletion. The next highest-voted answer there also concurs.